# Pandas Data Frame - Remove Overlapping Intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, overlap

Suppose that you have a Pandas data frame that can be created using code below:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'start_date': ['2021-07-01', '2021-07-02', '2021-07-03',
                    '2021-07-04', '2021-07-05', '2021-07-06'],
     'end_date': ['2021-07-03', '2021-07-04', '2021-07-05',
                  '2021-07-06', '2021-07-07', '2021-07-08'],
     'returns': [1, 1, 0.99, 0.98, 0.99, 0.97]})
test_df = test_df.sort_values('returns', ascending=False)
```

Assuming that `returns` are always sorted what would be the efficient way to remove overlapping intervals? I do not want to use loops as the data set is large is there a vectorized approach to achieve the output below?

**Expected Output**

```
+------------+------------+---------+
| start_date |  end_date  | returns |
+------------+------------+---------+
| 2021-07-01 | 2021-07-03 |       1 |
| 2021-07-05 | 2021-07-07 |    0.99 |
+------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: So if the `end_date` is the same as a `start_date` that is an overlap?

Comment: yes that is an overlap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an answer from @mozway [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68627118/check-if-rows-date-range-overlap-any-previous-rows-date-range-in-python-panda) that works without a loop by using [`np.triu()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) (numpy's upper triangle).

Slightly changing it for your DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
test_df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(test_df["start_date"])
test_df["end_date"] = pd.to_datetime(test_df["end_date"])

a = np.triu(test_df['end_date'].values > test_df['start_date'].values[:, None])
b = np.triu(test_df['start_date'].values < test_df['end_date'].values[:, None])
test_df[(a & b).sum(0) == 1]
#  start_date   end_date  returns
#0 2021-07-01 2021-07-03     1.00
#4 2021-07-05 2021-07-07     0.99
```

## Explanation:

```
test_df['end_date'].values > test_df['start_date'].values[:, None]
#array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
#       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#       [False, False, False,  True, False,  True]])
```

This returns an array where the end_date values are greater than the start_date values.  This looks at each combination of start date and end date (with each end date as a column, and each start date as a row.  If the condition is met, then `True` is returned.

Taking the upper triangle of this means that only combinations where the start date comes with or before the end date (in terms of `test_df` rows) are `True`, with the rest `False`

`b` on the other hand looks for all instances where the end date is greater than the start dates (with each start date as a column, and each end date as a row).  For the first row of `test_df['start_date'].values < test_df['end_date'].values[:, None]`, it is looking at combinations of the first end date `2021-07-03` and whether it is greater than the start dates.

The upper triangle of this means that only occurrences where the start date is before the end date in the dataframe are `True`.

Deconstructing the last line `test_df[(a & b).sum(0) == 1]`:

- `(a & b)` is an array where `True` occurs where both arrays are `True`.
- `(a & b).sum(0)` sums each column of this array where `True == 1` and `False == 0`.
- `(a & b).sum(0) == 1` is rows where there is only one occurrence of `a` and `b` being `True` together.  We only want these because we want rows where:

1. the start date is less than a previous (or current) end date

AND

2. the end date is greater than a previous (or current) start date

HOWEVER

If this occurs more than once, then there must be an overlap.  Because the leading diagonal will always be `True` (as the end date for a given dataframe row must ALWAYS be greater than the start date) for this scenario, if this occurs more than once this means:

1. The start date is less than a previous end date AND the current end date

AND

2. The end date is greater than a previous starting date AND the current start date

Which means that there MUST be an overlap here.

I understand this is quite confusing, but it does make sense!

Comment: Can you explain a bit?

Comment: I have given an explanation (which I know if quite confusing, but I couldn't think of any way to make is more simple!).

Comment: what if there's another column - let's say it's an id of a component and the overlapping intervals must be removed per ID. how could you addapt thiss code without using a loop?