# Removing overlapping events from data table with intervals

Tags: python, r, matlab, vectorization, intervals

Given a large (> 100MB) data frame of events with location and timestamps, how can I remove events synchronously occurring in all locations (i.e. putative noise) in *R*, *MATLAB* or *Python* (with reasonable performance)?

A minimal specification of the problem in *R* would be:

```
pixel <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
start <- c(1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 1, 4, 7)
end   <- c(2, 4, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 5, 9)

events <- data.frame(cbind(pixel, start, end))

# there was an event between 1 and 2s detected everywhere;
# this event would therefore be removed in the desired output:
#
#  pixel start end
#      1     3   4
#      1     6   7
#      1     8   9
#      2     3   4
#      2     5   6
#      2     7   8
#      2     8   9
#      3     4   5
#      3     7   9
```

I had tried to solve the problem with loops, but the solution is slow. (Experts sometimes recommend to "vectorize" calculations, but I found no way to get rid of the loops.)

Additionally, I had found a related post for the problem in *Python* on [Pandas Data Frame - Remove Overlapping Intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72242090/pandas-data-frame-remove-overlapping-intervals).

It seems to me that this type of problem should be a common one and is probably already solved by a package, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Why would pixels 1 and 2 with start == 3 and end == 4 still be there?

Comment: Because there's no event on pixel detected between 3 and 4 seconds in pixel 3. We only want to remove those events, which occurred across all locations.

Comment: I think you need to explain your logic better - where is the `location` parameter that you speak of?

Comment: Location is equivalent to pixel, since it is about square units. Sorry, I had thought too long oft a solution and should habe mentioned that!

Comment: FYI, the use of `data.frame(cbind(...))` is _at best_ inefficient, it can do nothing that `data.frame(...)` itself cannot do. Commonly, when all of the arguments are not the same class, it ends up corrupting (coercing to another class) one or more variables. Not sure where that's taught, it's _never_ useful or necessary.

Comment: You say "there was an event between 1 and 2s detected everywhere". However, an event with start time 1 and end time 2 only occurred at pixels 1 and 2, not at pixel 3. As HoelR said, you should explain your question better

Answer (score 3):

I think your expected output is incomplete and has more rows than it should. Namely, all three `pixel`s have an event between `1, 2` and `8, 9`, so we should be removing two rows from each `pixel`.

Here's a `data.table` solution. Note that since we want the comparison to be right-side-open (i.e., `1, 3` does not overlap with `3, 4`), I'll momentarily decrease `end` by an iota, set the keys (required for `foverlaps`), check for overlaps, then return the iota I subtract.

```r
library(data.table)
events <- data.table(pixel, start, end)

# subtract an iota from `end`, needed for right-side-open
iota <- 1e-9
events[, end := end - iota]
setkey(events, start, end)
events[, overlaps := foverlaps(.SD, events)[, uniqueN(pixel), by = c("i.start", "i.end")]$V1, by = .(pixel)]
# Key: <start, end>
#     pixel start   end overlaps
#     <num> <num> <num>    <int>
#  1:     1     1     2        3
#  2:     2     1     2        3
#  3:     3     1     3        3
#  4:     1     3     4        2
#  5:     2     3     4        2
#  6:     3     4     5        1
#  7:     2     5     6        1
#  8:     1     6     7        1
#  9:     2     7     8        2
# 10:     3     7     9        3
# 11:     1     8     9        3
# 12:     2     8     9        3
```

The `overlaps` column now represents a count for how many total unique `pixel` values are found in the set of overlapping time ranges, including "self". When this number is the same as the number of total unique `pixel` values, then we have rows that overlap with all other groups.

```r
out <- events[uniqueN(pixel) > overlaps, ][, end := end + iota]
setorder(out, pixel, start, end)
out
#    pixel start   end overlaps
#    <num> <num> <num>    <int>
# 1:     1     3     4        2
# 2:     1     6     7        1
# 3:     2     3     4        2
# 4:     2     5     6        1
# 5:     2     7     8        2
# 6:     3     4     5        1
```

Follow-up proof, by-row:

```
    pixel start   end
    <num> <num> <num>
 1:     1     1     2  # overlaps row 5, 10      ALL3
 2:     1     3     4  # overlaps row 6
 3:     1     6     7  # no overlaps
 4:     1     8     9  # overlaps row 9, 12      ALL3
 5:     2     1     2  # overlaps row 1, 10      ALL3
 6:     2     3     4  # overlaps row 2
 7:     2     5     6  # no overlaps
 8:     2     7     8  # no overlaps
 9:     2     8     9  # overlaps row 4, 12      ALL3
10:     3     1     3  # overlaps row 1, 5
11:     3     4     5  # no overlaps
12:     3     7     9  # overlaps rot 4, 12      ALL3
```

`ALL3` rows should be removed (by my interpretation of your logic).

Comment: Thanks , your algorithm even detected the overlap between 8 and 9 seconds, which I had missed manually. The overlap between 1 and 2 is the one I had seen and removed.